# Creating a normal distribution in Python over many standard deviations with a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, standard-deviation

I'm trying to create a list of arrays consisting of random values according to a normal distribution with different standard deviations of the normal distribution for each array. What I should have is in the first array all normal distribution values should have a standard deviation of 0.01, in the second array all should have a standard deviation of 0.02, and so on all the way up to 1. My code looks like this:

```
noise_stdv = np.linspace(0.01, 1, 100)
for i in noise_stdv:
   noise1 = [np.random.normal(0, noise_stdv, 100) for i in range(100)]
```

But this creates a list in such a way that the first element in each array has a standard deviation of 0.01, the second element has 0.02 and so on, instead of the whole first array having a standard deviation of 0.01 etc.

How do I make it so that the for loop runs and creates an array for each element in noise_stdv instead of running for every element in it for each array? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the same variable over and over again, and passing in the vector of standard deviations rather than a single one to each iteration. Just do the list comprehension once:

```
noise_stdv = np.linspace(0.01, 1, 100)
noises = [np.random.normal(0, std, 100) for std in noise_stdv]
```